# Birthday problem with duplicate days of the month

Tags: probability

"Consider the birthday problem except that you ask for duplicate days of the month (assume each month has exactly 30 days)."

The answer I got as well as the one given in the book is 7. After 7 people, we have probability of greater than 0.5. More precisely P(7) = 1 - 0.469155 = 0.530845.

Initially when I was thinking about the problem I was confused on how to account for the 12 months. But as can be shown, the number of months is irrelevant. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because no matter the number of months, there are only $30$ possible answers to the question "On which day of the month were you born?".

Think in a bag with many dices. Take two dices from the bag, roll them and consider the probability that you get the same number in both dices. Does matter at all the number of dices in the bag?

Comment: I see. It's sort of like the original birthday problem; it doesn't matter which year they were born in, just which one of 365 days. Given that the probabilities for all years are iid, it doesn't make a difference. But if all die were not iid and say a particular color die was loaded then that would affect the probabilities. Correct?

Comment: You got the point :)